# Using loop to populate a matplotlib plot in Python

Tags: matplotlib

I have a question pertaining to how I can use a loop to populate a matplotlib grid (2 by 2), with each iteration of the k means algorithm ( total of 4 iterations). I am new to python, and programming in general so I don't have much understanding of how to do it. Below is the code (not all of it) and the current output I am getting. Thank you!

```
lt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10,5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)

for itr in range(4): # set number of k-mean iterations
    # initialize distance and cluster membership
    cluster_ind = np.zeros(len(X))
    distance = np.zeros((len(X), k))
    
    for i, j in enumerate(C):
        distance[:, i] = EuclideanDistance(j, X)
        cluster_ind = np.argmin(distance, axis = 1)
    
    
    for i in range(k):
        C[i] = np.mean(X[cluster_ind == i], axis = 0)
    
        plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], s=8)
```

The output is as follows;

[Plot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyk50.png)

Comment: Is your question about how to fill in the subplots that you created? See this - https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html there are a lot of examples on how to create and populate subplots. Doing this in a loop should be just a matter of indexing into the correct subplot.

Comment: Basically, after each iteration of kmeans, I want to plot the centroids and the clusters in a single plot. How exactly would I index into a correct subplot? Would I have to create a new for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to populate each subplot, you can just do this -

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2)
fig.suptitle('Sharing x per column, y per row')
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2.plot(x, y**2, 'tab:orange')
ax3.plot(x, -y, 'tab:green')
ax4.plot(x, -y**2, 'tab:red')

for ax in fig.get_axes():
    ax.label_outer()
```

Specific to you code, when you create the subplot command, create a bunch of subplot objects (`ax1`...`ax4` in this case). Instead of having `plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], s=8)` inside your loop, have `ax.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], s=8)`. (replace `ax` with `ax1` when itr=0, and `ax2` when itr=1 and so on).

To be more specific, in your code, I would do this inside your loop,

```
if itr == 0:
    ax1.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], s=8)
elif itr == 1:
    ax2.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], s=8)
elif itr == 2:
    ax3.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], s=8)
elif itr == 3:
    ax4.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], s=8)
```

I would do this instead of doing `plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], s=8)`.

(The code snippet taken directly from the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html))

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but I still don't understand how to automate the population, in the sense where during the first iteration, it populates the [0,0] plot, and during the second it populates the [0,1] plot. I apologize for my ignorance. Maybe im missing something that is obvious

Comment: I edited the answer to be more specific. Not sure if this is what you meant, but this is one way of doing this.